# Android view to bitmap with tranparency

Tags: android, bitmap, png

I need to convert TextView to bitmap. TextView has transparency using the setAlpha() method. I am using following code

```
Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(textView , 150);
try {
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, new FileOutputStream(watermarkImagePath));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int alpha) {
    view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint alphaPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    alphaPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
    alphaPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    Toast.makeText(VideoCaptureActivity.this, "alpha" + alpha, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    alphaPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,0,0,alphaPaint);
    view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight());
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

but the issue is that the result image has no transparency :(

Comment: use `Canvas#saveLayerAlpha` before calling `view.draw(canvas);`

Comment: @pskink what should be the parameters of Canvas#saveLayerAlpha

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#saveLayerAlpha(android.graphics.RectF,%20int,%20int)

Comment: I have added canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, 0, 0, 150, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG); before view.draw(canvas); but still the issue is there

Comment: do you know what is 0, 0, 0, 0 ?

Comment: my bad it should be 0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight(). but now the result images is blank and has no text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108264/discussion-between-muhammad-hamza-shahid-and-pskink).

Answer (score 2):

After trying different techniques what worked for me was to make bitmap from view with full opacity and then set tranparency of bitmap. Hope it will help others having same issue

```
Bitmap b = addTranparencyToBitmap(getBitmapFromView(view), (int)( view.getAlpha() * 255));
try {
   b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 95, new FileOutputStream(watermarkImagePath));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

 public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

public Bitmap addTranparencyToBitmap(Bitmap originalBitmap, int alpha) {
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
    Paint alphaPaint = new Paint();
    alphaPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
    canvas.drawBitmap(originalBitmap, 0, 0, alphaPaint);
    return newBitmap;
}
```